# Ubuntu 16.04 K3b install frozen

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, k3b

Noob here. Installing K3b and it has stalled.  I have tried through console and Software Center.  I have no idea what to do or what to check.  Can I "clear" the install processes that failed? Whenever I restart and try again the install bar jumps to halfway and freezes.

Edit: Tried to install on separate machine. Exact same problem, maybe this app cannot be installed when in China?

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalled Ubuntu from back-up.  After fresh install installed K3b from the terminal with no issues.  Must be a problem with the Software Center.